# Redirect to installed Page Tab after permission dialog

Tags: facebook, redirect, tabs

I want to redirect the user to the page tab he currently installed on a facebook page he owns.
To make this clear im talking about the install process of facebook page tabs.
I found several questions in the same direction but i couldn't find a correct way to do this.
This is the standard link to install a page tab.

"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL"

Because i dont know on which page a user will install the tab i can't set the next url properly.
This will lead me to redirect to some page i try to get these infos. However I'm not able to extract information about the page he used through signed request or the url schema.
Sometimes the url contained the id of the page the tab was installed, but this seems over.

"https://url/?tabs_added%5B379396442071062%5D=1#*=*"

**edit**: this url contains the IDs as array encode, thanks @ifaour: %5B379396442071062%5D -> 379396442071062

In my opinion this is such a standard use case to do for page tabs that i couldn't believe it's so hard to actually do this or find a solution for that.

Hope you can help!

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is possible currently.

Comment: As Donn Lee said, it may not be possible. However, I may have created a workaround when I tried to do something similar but didn't explore to much into. It was basically setting the next page url to a header redirect script that returned the user to the page tab. If I find it, I'll post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess there's nothing wrong with the current logic. Since you can add your app to a multiple pages at once with the [Add Page Tab dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/), Facebook is giving you control over the next step.

Facebook will return the ids of the selected pages by the admin from the dialog, and since the result could be more than one id, it's not advised to redirect the admin to the Facebook page tab even though it's possible with something like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/-/PAGE_ID?sk=app_APP_ID
```

Now a good practice to consider is to list the pages where the app was added to successfully (and maybe offer some "demos" or "next steps" to better advertise your solution).

Here's a quick code to handle the response:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['tabs_added'])) {
    $tabs_ids =  array_keys($_GET['tabs_added']);
    $comma_separated_ids = implode(",", $tabs_ids);
    $api_call = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+page_url,pic,name+FROM+page+WHERE+page_id+IN+($comma_separated_ids)";
    $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($api_call);
    $result = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
    if(!empty($result["data"])) {
        echo "Congratulations! You have successfully added our App to the following pages:<br />";
        foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
            echo "<img src=\"{$page['pic']}\" alt=\"{$page['name']}\" /> <a href=\"{$page['page_url']}\">{$page['name']}</a><br />";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "It seems that you didn't add our awesome app to any of your pages. Want to <a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&next=". urlencode("YOUR_URL") . "\">try again<a/>?";
}
```

This code would check if the user cancelled the dialog encouraging them one more time. And also retrieve the selected pages' name, picture and link to list them.

DISCLAIMER: this code is just an example, private and unpublished pages may not be retrieve in the FQL query.